# Pulling Celery Beat arguments from a database

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

Is there a way to give celery beat a callable that will return the arguments to pass to the message?  I would like to be able to pull data from the database to construct the arguments to pass to the celery queue.

What I would like to do would be something like this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-minut1': {
        'task': 'some_task',
        'schedule': timedelta(hours=1),
        'args': some_function_that_returns_a_tuple()
    },
}
```

Currently I have one machine adding messages to the queue and a different machine taking the messages off of the queue and processing them.  The machine that is adding the messages to the queue is hard coding it's arguments, but I would like for it to pull that info out of the database.

The only solution I can think of currently is for the machine that is adding messages to the queue to to run celery itself.  It would have a separate queue to run a command that adds messages to the original queue for the processing server.  This seems overly complicated and it seems like there should be a simpler solution.